# react-native ios app webview plays audio muted when screen turrned off

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I built a react-native webview app which has audio when the screen turns off the audio keep playing in android while it turned off in ios.
is there any solution ?

Comment: What package are you using right now for audio playing? Show the code in the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the `Background Modes` of `Xcode` project should be enabled.

If not enabled, go to Xcode project -> Select the target -> Capabilities section -> Background Modes -> Turn it on.

Then select `Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture`.

[image]

**Code:**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import SoundPlayer from 'react-native-sound-player';

export default class Touchables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  playTrack() {
    try {
      SoundPlayer.playUrl('http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3')
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Cannot play the file')
      console.log('cannot play the song file', e)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="play me" onPress={this.playTrack} />
      </View>
   );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 100,
  },
});
```